# removing words from array of string based on its dict value in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of patterns stored in variable

```
resultSynRealUni=["Adam went","Alex is in school", "John met Mark"]
```

lets assume "went " & "is" & "school" and "Mark" their dict is below 4 (a certain threshold)

**so I want the output to be**

```
 finalPatternSynReal=["Adam ","Alex  in ", "John met "]
```

I tried this but for some reason its not working

```
finalPatternSynReal=[]

for place in resultsSynRealUni:
    for word in place.strip().split():
        wordUni=u"" + u"".join(word) + u"" 
        if dict[wordUni] <= 4: 
            place=place.replace(wordUni,"").strip()

    finalPatternSynReal.append(place)
print("Final Pattern is")
print(finalPatternSynReal)
```

Output:
am
ex

Note: In my code I am using arabic not english.

Comment: Why are you using `u"" + u"".join(word) + u""`? That doesn't do anything other than decode to Unicode (using the ASCII codec).

Comment: And can you share `dict` with us (which you really shouldn't be calling `dict` as that is masking the built-in type). It sounds as if `dict[wordUni] <= 4` is never true.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used that line cause its actually in Arabic language but I posted my question in English so that it could be understandable 

the thing is I can't share the real dict score, do u mind checking out my real question that I posted it using the Arabic Language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816893/how-to-remove-a-word-from-an-array-in-python

Comment: People there are asking the exact same thing I am asking. Share `dict`.

Comment: You should share your `dict` instance (and please rename it to `d`, or `dic`, or `dict_` or `scores`. i.e.: how do you instanciate it, and what does it contain.

Comment: "I can't share the real dict" <- Then make one up that fits your example in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have:

```
resultSynRealUni=["Adam went","Alex is in school", "John met Mark"]
```

and a `scores` dictionary as below:

```
scores = { "went": 1, "is": 2, "school": 3, "Mark": 2 }
```

what you want could be:

```
finalPatternSynReal = []
for statement in resultSynRealUni:
    out_stmt = []
    for token in statement.strip().split():
        if not (token in scores.keys() and scores[token] <= 4):
            out_stmt.append(token)
    finalPatternSynReal.append(" ".join(out_stmt))
```

result:

```
>>> finalPatternSynReal
['Adam', 'Alex in', 'John met']
```

*(sorry for being brief and straightforward about the solution, but I got some friends at home, and I took 5min to answer your Q ;-) )*

HTH